# Ubuntu installation hangs at partition menu

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, partitioning, system-installation

Hello guys I'm trying to dual boot ubuntu on my ssd with windows 7 64 installed. I had already reserved 40gb free space for it in advance. I tried to install both 14.04.1 and 12.04 with no success. The both  hang at the partition menu. Any suggestions?

edit:

Ok so I managed to get this during an installation attempt.

http://oi61.tinypic.com/rlidqe.jpg

Comment: Are you able to mount your 40GB whole space as ROOT ("/") only or system just stuck at partition MENU??

Comment: I've had this problem before too.  I believe I was able to get past it with a reboot and re-try, but it's been a while now.

Answer (score -1):

If you are installing Ubuntu desktop, it will sense the windows partition, then ask you if you want to keep the windows partition, and install Ubuntu alongside, or delete the windows partition, and use the whole disk for Ubuntu. After answering this question, you should be able to use the default disk partition it provides, and not go into the partition menu at all.

Comment: the question is not "how do I partition my disk?".  The question is "why does the tool hang when I try to partition my disk?"